# Using 5.1 Dolby with Xbox One

Tags: xbox-one, audio-hardware

I have a Xbox One and a tv decoder (for cable television) connected via HDMI to the television.

Yesterday I've received and "old" Philips 5.1 Home Theater that doesn't have HDMI inputs, but only one RCA inputs.

My first question is simple: If I connect the TV to the Home Theater AVR, the audio output will always be a 5.1 ? If I turn on the Xbox One does the audio come out as a true 5.1 or does it simply sound like a stereo "adapted" to a 5.1?

If a simple connection like this is not effective (basically every device connected to the TV and the TV connected to the AVR) How can I set everything so that every device's output audio is a 5.1 ?

Comment: Does it have optical?

Comment: no. Just two RCAs T.T

Answer (score 1):

As by the [Xbox.com page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/system/configure-audio-settings) on how to configure your audio settings, the One does support 5.1 just fine via HDMI.

But although your Xbox One supports it, your Home Theatre does not. RCA is a dated technology that is not able to transfer the data necessary for Dolby 5.1 as RCA only supports two channels (as in Stereo). Depending on the device producing the audio, it might try to approximate Dolby 5.1 but it will only ever be an approximation.

Comment: ok and the solution is...... ?! Buying another AVR?!

Comment: @LeonGuerrero yes, or if you have an amplifier with HDMI inputs and an RCA outputs then you can bridge the sound to your 5.1 sound system, but it won't be real 5.1, just a virtually created 5.1 from stereo source.